# Unable to locate element using all the element locators that I know the HTML is build using CSS selector

Tags: java, css, selenium

This is the HTML page I'm trying to locate the financial report. I have tried to use XPath, CSS selector but no luck:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>                        
        <!-- ANALYSIS -->
        <div style="margin:10px">ANALYSIS</div>

        <li class='has-sub'><a href='javascript:void(0)'><div>Accruals</div></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='/financial/dailyAccrualMaintain.do?action=DAILY_MAINTAIN_OPEN&clear=true'><div>Daily</div></a></li>
                <li class='last'><a href='/financial/accrual.do?action=list1&clear=true'><div>Monthly</div></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='/financial/financialReports.do?action=LIST_REPORTS&clear=true'><div>Financial Reports</div></a></li>
        <li><a href='/financial/validationReports.do?action=LIST_REPORTS&clear=true'><div>Validation Reports</div></a></li>
        <li><a href='/financial/financialCheck.do?action=OPEN&clear=true'><div>Financial Check</div></a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Java code where I used CSS selector to locate the element and I also used wait untill element is visible:

```
private final String finacialReportpath = "div#cssmenu li:nth-child(3)"; 
    @FindBy(css = finacialReportpath)
    private WebElement finacialReport;

public void clickfinacialReport() {

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(finacialReportpath)));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(finacialReportpath)));

        this.finacialReport.click();

}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `click` on an `li` to do? Perhaps you want to select the `a` instead? It's got a more unique set of attributes to select with, which is useful...

Comment: Div cannot be a direct child of ul - you have invalid html which is probably why your selector does not work

Comment: IMO, `financial report` alone can't be selected, either you have to select **Daily** or **Monthly** first then you can invoke click on corresponding element pertaining to `financial report`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath:

```
//a[contains(.,'Financial Reports')]
```

and still, if you are not able to find it than make sure whether you are in any frame or not.
If present in the frame then switch to it and then try to find the element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to click the link, but you're selecting the `li` instead. Perhaps select the link (which also has the advantage of having a fairly unique set of attributes):

```
private final String finacialReportpath = "a[href^='/financial/financialReports.do']";
// Changed -------------------------------^
@FindBy(css = finacialReportpath)
private WebElement finacialReport;

public void clickfinacialReport(){

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(finacialReportpath)));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(finacialReportpath)));

    this.finacialReport.click();

}
```

`^=` means "[starts with](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings)".

Comment: Still can not locate the element